# sort positive float numbers in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to sort positive float numbers in the most efficient way possible. I have more or less 10k elements.

I thought about radix sort (best one so far) or bucket sort, someone has some suggestions and why.
ty

Comment: @ExceptionalNullPointer That's C++, not C.

Comment: Why not use the built-in `qsort()`?

Comment: @Barmar: Because `qsort` calls the comparison function by pointer, which is an unnecessary performance impediment that can be replaced by a direct call or inline comparison in a custom quicksort implementation and because other sort techniques may be faster than quicksort.

Comment: @EricPostpischil for ~10k numbers I don't think it's a overhead. Worst case this function will be called nlog(n) = 13 * 10000 times. Given the modern computer cache the stack required to execute this qsort function can fit in a cache block so we don't even need to worry about the stack pushes needed for the function call

Comment: @MadhusoodanP: The core of a quicksort is a compare, swap, and increment, which might be implemented with about half a dozen instructions. Replacing the compare with a function call will more than double the work involved. It is a huge waste. The function call requires two argument pushes/moves, a call, a frame pointer push, a frame pointer pop, and a return. Additionally, inside the function, there has to be code to prepare a return value of negative, zero, or positive, which requires at least a compare and several instructions to prepare the various return values.

Comment: @ericpostpischil your are right. It's around 8 instructions for this application per function call. It will be interesting to see any quick sort implemention in assembly, can you please point me to one if you have any reference

Answer (score 3):

Can you elaborate by describing the difficulty you are facing while implementing the bucket or radix sort? If it's fine (not a homework), you can use the built-in qsort (as suggested by @Barmar). Here is the declaration of this method.

```
/* from man pages */
#include <stdlib.h>

void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));

void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
          int (*compar)(const void *, const void *, void *),
          void *arg);
```

You can find the manual of qsort (or any such public libc functions) by using below command in linux (or google "man qsort")

```
man qsort
```

Here is an example program which uses qsort for sorting floating point numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* this function will be used by qsort to compare elements */
int cmp(const void *v1, const void *v2) {
        float f1=*((float*)v1);
        float f2=*((float*)v2);
        if(f1 < f2)
                return -1;
        else if(f1 > f2)
                return 1;
        return 0;
}
int main() {
        int i;
        float x[] = {0.2, 0.3, 0.1};
        qsort(x, 3, sizeof(float), cmp);
        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
                printf("%f\n", x[i]);
}
```

You can read about quick sort here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Read more about function pointers here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer